# Strong contraction of hyperbolic space

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

I'm trying to study Hyperbolic geometry, but I can not understand the following statement.

> Let $X$ be a $δ$-hyperbolic space.
>   Then, there exists $M > 0$ such that for any geodesic $γ$, and any ball $B_r(x)$ of arbitrary radius that is disjoint from $γ$, the closest-point projection of the ball to the geodesic has diameter $≤ M$.

I want to know the proof of the question. (Maybe $M = 5δ$)

If anyone could help, It would be really appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that the statement is easy to prove when $X$ is a real tree. Therefore, suppose that the general statement fails in some hyperbolic space $X$, and take a sequence of balls $B_n$ and geodesics $\gamma_n$ such that the projection of $B_n$ on $\gamma_n$ has diameter at least $n$; then deduce that your statement fails in some ultralimit $\left( \frac{1}{n} X , y_n \right) \to (Y,y)$. Since $Y$ is a real tree, you get a contradiction.

**EDIT:** In *Géométrie et théorie des groupes, les groupes hyperboliques de Gromov* (proposition 10.2.1 page 108), a more general statement is proved using a quantitative approximation of finite subspaces by simplicial trees. In particular, if $B_r$ is a ball at distance at least $r$ from a geodesic $\gamma$, then the projection of $B_r$ on $\gamma$ has diameter at most $12 \delta$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I can understand that the statement is true if X is a real tree. But, what's n and y_n ? Is n a radius of B ?

Comment: And why the lim X(δ-hyperbolic)/n = Y(a real tree)?

Comment: $n$ is just the index of the sequence; it corresponds also to a lower bound on the diameter of the projection of $B_n$ on $\gamma_n$, by definition. Then, $Y$ is a real tree because it is a $0$-hyperbolic geodesic space. Of course, you have to choose $y_n$ carefully, but I just gave a hint.

Comment: Thanks. Is y_n a geodesic triangle ? What does the pair (X/n , y_n) mean ?

Comment: Oh... I understand. I did't know the definition of the ultra limit.

Comment: I agree, and there probably exists a proof avoiding ultralimits. But such a proof would be, I think, a laborious manipulation of inequalities. It is why I used ultralimits: thinking of hyperbolic spaces as approximations of real trees seems to be more natural here.

Comment: I found a more quantitative solution in the book *Géométrie et théorie des groupes, les groupes hyperboliques de Gromov*.

Comment: Thank you. It is difficult for me to understand the definition of the ultra limit. So, I'll read the book, and consider the statement again.

Comment: Was the book translated into English?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Oh..I see. I'll try to read the book.

Comment: @Seirios I am struggling with the same statement. Do I understand that correctly, one takes balls $B_n$ and geodesics $\gamma_n$ that satisfy $\operatorname{diam}(\pi_{\gamma_n}(B_n)) \geq n$ then takes the ultralimit of $(X,d/n)$ which for $\delta-$hyperbolic spaces is the asymptotic cone $\operatorname{Cone}_\omega(X,d)$ which is a $0$-hyperbolic space.

Comment: Yes, it is the main idea. But the conclusion does not immediately follow, further work is needed.